# android:required="false" is being ignored in uses-feature tag

Tags: android

Following is from **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

```
<permission
    android:name="com.kivi.kividoctors.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />
```

But Google keep showing me following 3 features in a list when I update the Application. It just ignore the **android:required** property for camera's features. Where as it works for telephony feature.

```
android.hardware.CAMERA
android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS
android.hardware.camera.FLASH
```

I've tried all the possible ways I could find on SO, but couldn't find the solution.
 Is there anything I'm missing to get rid of above 3 features from the list?

---

**Update:**

Also tried capitalizing feature in **android:name** property like this.
 (I know this is not right, but still I tried and no luck with that too)

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.CAMERA" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.FLASH" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Perhaps a library is requiring the feature. There should be a manifest merger report in `build/outputs/logs/` of your module. It will be a bit difficult to understand, but hopefully you can find references to this `uses-feature` element and see what all is contributing to it.

Comment: Is there any way I can override library's Manifest?

Comment: You should be able to, [using `tools:replace`](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Markers). Just make sure that you do not try using the library when the hardware requirements are not met.

Comment: Thanks, That worked very well! Please make it an answer for future SO users.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently, a library had `<uses-feature>` for these and marked them as required. If any contributor to the manifest marks a feature as required, it winds up as required in the final merged manifest.

When you encounter this, first, try to identify what library (or libraries) are doing this. The manifest merger report (should be in `build/output/logs/` of your app module) is clunky to read but should point out who the culprits are.

Next, add `tools:replace="required"` to the `<uses-feature>` elements in your manifest, to indicate that you want to overrule any lower-priority manifests, such as those from libraries.

Finally, be very careful about using the libraries that you identified earlier. They are expecting features that you explicitly are not requiring. Using those libraries on devices where those features are not being met is risky.

Answer (score 4):

add before the permissions, that should help

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).